# Setting parts of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

Suppose I have list

```
a = Range[10]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

in which I want to set some elements to be a list

```
a[[4 ;; 7]] = {1, 2, 3};
```

> `{1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 8, 9, 10}`

Which is fine and dandy unless my part span is the same length as my list:

```
a[[4 ;; 6]] = {1, 2, 3};
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

How can I force the assignment to behave consistently?  In my case, I always want the first behaviour.  But conceivably someone might always want the second behaviour with errors if the lengths don't match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(a[[#]] = {1, 2, 3}) & /@ Range[4, 6];
```

You get:

```
In[1]:= a

Out[1]= {1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

A convenient thing to remember is that if your elements are not sequential it is still easy to set up:

```
(a[[#]] = {1, 2, 3}) & /@ {1, 3, 10};

In[2]:= a

Out[2]= {{1, 2, 3}, 2, {1, 2, 3}, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Comment: but this doesn't automate keeping the behaviour of `Set` consistent as the question asks (although it does do what is desired). then again neither does any other answer, nor anything I can come up with...

Comment: The in-place modification aspect of this answer works best for my actual problem.  But as acl says, the more general question remains.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps

```
a = Range[10]

a[[4 ;; 6]] = Sequence@{1, 2, 3};
```

Returns

```
{1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

However, as Mr.Wizard noted in a comment, this is a LIIIEEE. If you do `Information[a]` you see that the `Sequence` is actually being saved. I find this weird, but anyway, can be solved with an extra

```
a=a
```

Also, forcing the lhs and rhs lists to be a different size should work 
`a[[{4,5,6,4}]]={1, 2, 3}`

Comment: This actually doesn't work quite seamlessly.  Try `Information[a]`.

Comment: Oooooops, thanks

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's weird that essentially with Set this returns a delayed assignment. Wasn't expecting that, good catch

Comment: take another look.  If it doesn't work, delete again. :^)

Comment: +1 as this is the only answer in the spirit of the question (or anyway what I took to be the spirit of the question)

Comment: +1. The behavior you were puzzled with is not weird IMO, but actually the only behavior consistent with the low-level nature of assignments. I give some arguments for that in my answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/b7303eafccee6d5a). Also, [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/8d04685fd7283130) seems on-topic.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yeah, your right, doesn't seem strange now. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way that's in two-steps, but works nevertheless:

```
a[[4 ;; 6]] = \[FormalF][1, 2, 3];
a = a /. \[FormalF] -> List
Out[1]= {1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Here's another solution using `MapAt`, but this loses the convenience of indexing with `Span`.

```
a = MapAt[{1, 2, 3} &, a, Transpose[{Range[4, 6]}]]
Out[2]= {1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

But the standard way to replace elements in a safe manner and for cases where you want different replacements for each, is to use `ReplacePart` as:

```
a = ReplacePart[a, Transpose[{Range[4, 6]}] -> {1, 2, 3}]
Out[3]= {1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Answer (score 5):

After reading the answers, this is one way more to do it (maybe too simple):

```
a[[4 ;; 6]] = ConstantArray[{1, 2, 3}, 3];
```

Thinking in it, you can do your own simple `Set`:

```
Attributes[simpleSet] = {HoldFirst};
simpleSet[lhs_, rhs_] := 
  With[{newrhs = ConstantArray[rhs, Length[lhs]]}, lhs = newrhs];
```

And use it as `Set`:

```
simpleSet[a[[4 ;; 6]], {1, 2, 3}];
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

And it returns the same as `Set` returns: what it is assigned.

```
a
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```