# Assigning Sequence to Part of a SparseArray (bug?)

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, sparse-arrays

[`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)

> ▪ You can make an assignment like `t[[spec]]=value` to modify any part or sequence of parts in an expression.
>
> ▪ If `expr` is a `SparseArray` object, `expr[[...]]` gives the parts in the corresponding ordinary array.

[`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html)

> ▪ List and matrix operations are typically set up to work as they do on `Normal[SparseArray[...]]`.
>
> ▪ `Part` extracts specified parts of the array represented by a `SparseArray` object, rather than parts of the `SparseArray` expression itself.

```
array = Range[10]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)

array[[2]] = Sequence[0, 0, 0];

array
(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)

sparse = SparseArray[Range[10]];

sparse[[2]] = Sequence[0, 0, 0];

sparse[[2]]
(* {10} *)

ArrayRules[sparse]
(* ArrayRules::rect: Nonrectangular array encountered. >> *)
(* ArrayRules[SparseArray[Automatic, {10}, 0,
     {1, {{0, 10}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}}, 
     {1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}]] *)
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: After reading [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3382/7288) I think that maybe the former case with `List`s works only by a happy accident.

Comment: You might find [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/leonid$20sequence$20assignment/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jQRoX9coMTA/1pgIFA71CAsJ) interesting, as well as the other one linked to there in my post there.

Answer (score 7):

#### Analysis

It indeed looks like a borderline bug to me. Let us see what is happening. The first observation here is that part assignment does its job all right:

```
sparse = SparseArray[Range[10]];
sparse[[2]] = Sequence[0, 0, 0];
```

so that

```
?sparse
```

> ```
> Global`sparse
> sparse=SparseArray[Automatic,
>    {10},0,{1,{{0,10},{{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}}},
>    {1,Sequence[0,0,0],3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
> ]
> ```

you can see that the actual rule for `sparse` was updated correctly.

The next observation is that the main culprit is the `SparseArray` object, which evaluates, and in particular the `Sequence` inside the list of elements gets spliced, as it should according to the main evaluation procedure:

```
sparse

(* 
     SparseArray[
        Automatic,{10},0,{1,{{0,10},{{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}}},
       {1,0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
     ]
*)
```

while this is consistent with the evaluation sequence, this is where it goes wrong. To avoid this, either `SparseArray` should be `HoldAll`:

```
SetAttributes[SparseArray, HoldAll]
```

and then it works:

```
ArrayRules[sparse]

(* 
  {{1}->1,{2}->Sequence[0,0,0],{3}->3,{4}->4,{5}->5,{6}->6,
    {7}->7,{8}->8,{9}->9,{10}->10,{_}->0}
*)
```

or, the elements inside of `SparseArray` should be held in some holding wrapper (`Hold` etc), rather than `List`.

```
ClearAttributes[SparseArray, HoldAll]
```

The second option would require significant changes in the `SparseArray` representation, so it is unlikely that such a change can be considered. I can't tell off hand whether making `SparseArray` `HoldAll` can break anything.

#### Workarounds

You can create a dynamic environment to do that locally:

```
ClearAll[withHoldingSparseArray];
SetAttributes[withHoldingSparseArray,HoldAll];
withHoldingSparseArray[code_]:=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{SparseArray},
       SetAttributes[SparseArray,HoldAll];
       code
    ];
```

so that

```
withHoldingSparseArray[ArrayRules[sparse]]

(* 
  {{1}->1,{2}->Sequence[0,0,0],{3}->3,{4}->4,{5}->5,{6}->6,
    {7}->7,{8}->8,{9}->9,{10}->10,{_}->0}
*)
```

As another alternative, you can create a dynamic environment where you make `Sequence` inert:

```
ClearAll[withInertSequence];
SetAttributes[withInertSequence,HoldAll];
withInertSequence[code_]:=
    Module[{result,sequence},                        
        Block[{Sequence=sequence},
            result=code
        ];
        sequence=Sequence;
        result
    ]
```

and this will also give the right result for your example:

```
withInertSequence[ArrayRules[sparse]]

(* 
  {{1}->1,{2}->Sequence[0,0,0],{3}->3,{4}->4,{5}->5,{6}->6,
    {7}->7,{8}->8,{9}->9,{10}->10,{_}->0}
*)
```

This method can however be more dangerous / prone to errors than the first one.

#### Conclusions

So, on one hand, `SparseArray` object evaluates precisely according to the standard evaluation semantics. On the other hand, this leads to behavior which one can probably classify as a bug. I'll file a report on this.