# Using Sequence to delete a part of an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, sequence

I thought that assigning `Sequence[]` to a part of an expression is an effective way to remove it. For example, the following code yields `{2,3,4,5}`:

```
xx = Range[5]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx
```

Thus, I expected the output of the following code to be `{3,4,5}`; but, I get `{2,3,4,5}` instead:

```
xx = Range[5]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx
```

Comment: Take a look at `xx = Range[5]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; OwnValues@xx`

Comment: @Kuba: That is very strange. It contradicts the help "Sequence objects will *automatically* be flattened out in all functions except those with attribute SequenceHold or HoldAllComplete. " (italics mine)

Comment: During evaluation I suppose but here it's trickier, but I would rather wait for someone with deeper understanding of the issue to explain.

Comment: I think I got it thanks to Kuba. The answer lies in `yy = xx; OwnValues[yy]` ;-)

Comment: Yes, `Sequence` objects are flattened **upon evaluation**. They won't be flattened without evaluation of the expression.

Comment: Just toss an `xx=xx` between your `...=Sequence[]` operations...

Comment: @ciao I'm very sorry to miss your comment.You earned all the credit actually.

Comment: This specific issue has come up before, either here or on Stack Overflow.  If anyone recalls please add a link for further review.

Comment: @yode - Oh, no worries *at all*, but thanks for caring!

Comment: Related: [(3382)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3382/121),
[(27563)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27563/121).  And MathGroup threads:  [11/5/09](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/b7303eafccee6d5a), [9/23/11](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/8d04685fd7283130)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### What happens to the list after we assign an element to `Sequence[]`

The answers given so far already contain most of the pieces needed to explain this behavior, but I decided to still add this answer.

This topic has been discussed many times in the past, although not on this site. [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/tzA-r8zubVo/0-yB06QCTE0J) is one such discussion, where I also contributed an answer. I will take my answer from there, and adopt it to this case.

Consider your example:

```
xx = Range[5]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx
```

Now, let us see what is in `xx`:

```
?xx
```

> ```
> Global`xx
>
> xx={Sequence[],2,3,4,5}
> ```

We see that the first element is still there.

#### Some reasoning behind this behavior

We don't really change  the size of a list (as stored in `OwnValues`etc) by assigning `Sequence[]` to some of its elements - `Sequence[]` is just as good  an element as anything else.

The important part to realize is that all the `Sequence[]` magic happens at
*evaluation stage* - the size of an *evaluated* list becomes  *effectively*
smaller as a result of evaluation (during which `Sequence`-s inside heads
without `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete` attribute are spliced).

This seems entirely consistent, given that lists are internally
implemented as arrays and then to really change the size of a list as it is
stored, we would generally  need O(n) operations where n is the size of the
list. OTOH, operations like `Part` and assignments should not be concerned with anything else than just assigning parts of expressions, and such list
rearrangements should be beyond their scope IMO.

#### Back to the example

Returning to your example, all subsequent assignments simply re-assign
`Sequence[]` to the first element. Since the list is not evaluated during the part assignment, `Sequence` splicing does not happen.

Here is one way to get the elements removed, which would further clarify things.

```
xx = Range[5];
xx[[1]] = Sequence[];
xx = xx
xx[[1]] = Sequence[];
xx = xx
xx[[1]] = Sequence[];
xx = xx

(*

  {2, 3, 4, 5}

  {3, 4, 5}

  {4, 5}
*)
```

In this case, the code does what we need - removes the first element each time. The key part here is the assignment `xx = xx`. In this case it is non-trivial, because we *do evaluate* `xx` on the r.h.s. during the assignment, the `Sequence` splicing proceeds as it should, and then we assigned the result (which no longer contains the original first element, and is one element smaller now), to the same variable.

Note however, that `xx = xx` is an O(n) operation if `xx` stores a list of length `n`, which contains one or more `Sequence[]` inside it. So, this method isn't really efficient. There is no magic here either, because there is no way you can remove an element of an array in O(1) time - you'd need a different data structure if you need fast element removals (such as a linked list, or actually an `Association`). That the element removal is hidden in this method by a high-level construct like `Sequence` does not change that fundamental fact.

#### Summary

What you have observed is a result of an interplay between evaluation and the way part assignments are performed. Here are some things to keep in mind regarding this:

- Part assignments fundamentally can not remove elements from an expression stored in a variable.
- Assigning `Sequence[]` (or `Nothing`, for that matter) to a part of an expression will not remove that part, but rather put there `Sequence[]` or `Nothing`. Indeed, this seems to be the only sensible behavior.
- Shrinking of expressions containing `Sequence[]` is an *evaluation-time effect*, while expressions stored in variables are kept unevaluated, also during part assignments.

These points together explain your observation. In fact, this is just one reason to avoid using `Sequence` as an element-removing device, when possible. There are other options available for that. If you really do want to change your expression (stored in a symbol) via `Sequence` part assignment, one way to do that is to reassign the expression to the variable, using `var = var` idiom, allowing it to evaluate.

Note however, that `var = var` is an O(n) operation, so that won't be very efficient if you only remove one or a few elements in a large list. Which is another argument against using `Sequence`, because it hides the underlying algorithmic complexity and may therefore result in performance surprises for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 5):

Noted the documentation of the [Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html)'s **Details**:

> Sequence objects will automatically be flattened out in all functions
>   except those with attribute SequenceHold or HoldAllComplete.

```
xx= Range@5;
Do[xx[[1]] = Nothing, 3];xx
```

> {2, 3, 4, 5}

It'll return a `list` just without first element.You should activate to remove the `Sequence[]` use `xx=xx`

```
xx = Range@5;
Do[xx[[1]] = Nothing; xx = xx, 3]; xx
```

> {4, 5}

As your case,you should add a `xx=xx` in the expression

```
xx = Range[5]; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx = xx; xx[[1]] = Sequence[]; xx
```

> {3, 4, 5}

Comment: Subjective comment: I think I wouldn't I understand it better as a newbie. First of all `Nothing` behaves the same way in this context. Moreover, "activate" is vague and leads to confusion with `Activate`. At the end, the last example does `xx = xx` once, is it on purpose or not, one could ask.

Comment: @Kuba A same confusion to me actually after I post this answer.I have tried `Activate` and `Evaluate`,but don't work both.I just give a work-around maybe.Wait better thinking can explain this behavior.