# List damaged after update with Nothing

Tags: list-manipulation

In version 10.4.1 (Win 7 Ent)  I am implementing an algorithm that needs to update a list after each pass. I initially coded this with `Nothing` by removing items in the list that where no longer needed after each processing pass. This did not result in the expected outcome and I eventually sourced the error to the use of `Nothing`.  A very minimal example follows.

```
SeedRandom[19384];
datN = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 10]
(* {2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

For this minimal example `FirstPosition[5]@datN` will represent the index of the item that needs to be removed after each processing pass. (*I'm not trying to delete all 5's in the real code.*) There are two `5`'s. I would expect the first in position 4 to be removed at the end of the first pass.

```
datN[[Echo@First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN
>> 4
(* {2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

Success! The first pass finds the first `5`, removes it, and updates `datN`. Or does it? Lets try the second pass which should remove the `5` in position 6.

```
datN[[Echo@First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN
>> 6
(* {2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

What has happened here? The correct position of 6 was identified but instead of removing the `5` there it removed the `2` in position 5. Let us try one more time to remove the `5` now in position 5.

```
datN[[Echo@First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN
>> 5
(* {2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

It has done it again. The correct position of 5 has been identified but the `1` in position 4 has been removed instead.

Now it gets interesting. On the fourth try and every subsequent try after the fourth it simply refuses to remove anything.

```
datN[[Echo@First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN
>> 4
(* {2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
```

The output above will repeat with the `datN` never being altered from the forth try onwards.  Very odd.

Have I completely missed something or is this a bug?  If so, is it still around in version 11?

**Update**

Clearly I have to live with it as it is. However, at this moment, I don't feel it is intuitively correct. I would understand the hold behavior if I used `SetDelayed` but having used `Set` it seems a reasonable expectation that the `Nothing`s be removed.  At least I understand its mechanism.  I am dating myself a bit here but I was expecting a `ReDim Preserve` type of behavior. *10 Internet points to anyone that gets that reference without looking it up.*

Comment: Can confirm this buggy behavior using Mathematica v11.0.0 under Windows 10.

Comment: @Karsten7. I will report to WRI.

Comment: To me it looks like there is some kind of caching going on and the reason there isn't removed anything on the forth try is, that at position 4 in the original `datN` was a `5`, that is already `Nothing` now.

Comment: Yeah, wow. Have a look at `Trace[datN[[Echo@First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing, 
 TraceInternal -> True]` after doing all these steps. There is a `{2, 1, 3, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 5, 2, 2, 2}` in it.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes. But it clearly goes against the definition of `Nothing` in the documentation. `Nothing` should be removed from `List`. `datN` is a list. In addition, there are no `Hold*` attributes on `datN`.

Comment: Completely agree with you. If it's not a bug in the implementation, than it is a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @Edmund It *should be removed* upon evaluation, what actually happens here, and there is no statement that it should be removed from the original unevaluated list.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Seems very odd that the documentation states "*It is not removed in expressions that are held or inactive*". `datN` is neither held nor inactive.

Comment: @Edmund `datN` in your code is modified *in place* without evaluation of the whole struct. Hence it is actually held unevaluated!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I used `Set`, not `SetDelayed`.

Comment: Clearly I have to live with it as it is. However, at this moment, I don't feel it is intuitively correct. At least I understand its mechanism.

Comment: I have marked this question as "already has an answer" because it is the same exact issue manifesting in a slightly different way.  Leonid's answer already includes `Nothing`.  This question will remain as a guidepost, but if desirable someone may wish to edit the original question to include `Nothing` as well.

Answer (score 9):

**This is not a bug.**

You are assuming that

```
arr = {1,2,3}
arr[[2]] = Nothing
```

removes the second element.  *It doesn't!*  It sets the second element to `Nothing`, just the same as if you used any other symbol.

What happens when you evaluate `arr` now is the following evaluation steps:

```
arr -> {1,Nothing,3}
{1,Nothing,3} -> {1,3}
```

However, the length of `arr` is still 3.

You can see this with

```
Definition[arr]
(* arr = {1, Nothing, 3} *)
```

If you want to remove that element, then you need the extra step

```
arr = arr
```

---

**Update:**  I see the Edmund's comment was upvoted by several people, which shows that there's a widespread misunderstanding about what `Nothing` does.  The documentation states that

> `Nothing` is removed as part of the standard evaluation process.

That is, it is removed during evaluation *when it appears explicitly as part of a list*.  It does not however interact in any way with `Set` or `Part`.  `arr[[2]] = Nothing` does not behave in a special way.  It just sets the second element of the array to `Nothing`.

Now when you evaluate `arr`, it goes through *two* evaluation steps, as I stated above, first into `{1,Nothing,3}` which then evaluates further into `{1,3}`.  Thus *the result of the evaluation of `arr`* is a length-2 list, and `Length[arr]` returns `2`.  This does not mean that `arr` itself is a length-2 list.  It only means that *it evaluates to a length-2 list*.  You can see with `OwnValues[arr]` that it has 3 elements, the second being `Nothing`.

Comment: I disagree.  Evaluate `Length@datN` after each pass. It decreases. Also the documentation says that `Nothing` is removed from `List`.  `datN` is a list. There are no `Hold*` `Attributes` on `datN`. The `Nothing`s should be removed as is reasonably expected.

Comment: +1 - I recall an exact case like this (I think we both answered with the same explanation). Possible dupe?

Comment: @Edmund Of course `Length[arr]` is 2 in my example because `Length` is not `HoldAll`!  Yes, `Nothing` is removed from a list *during evaluation*.  That is, after you evaluate `arr`, it changes to `{1, Nothing, 3}`, which then changes to `{1,3}`.  *However, `Nothing` doesn't interact with `Set` and `Part` in any way!*  The only special property is that it is removed during evaluation *when it explicitly appears in a list*.  You understood the documentation.

Comment: @ciao Here is your [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118108/unexpected-behavior-of-sequence-using-sequence-to-delete-parts-of-an-expressi). Wish I'd checked since it has a response by Leonid Shifrin that I am sure is much better than my own.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Do you have an opinion on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124046/12)?

Comment: @Szabolcs That looks like something I may have implemented, to spec. So I'm not inclined to comment other than to say "just doing my job". Maybe I should have an opinion on such things but that would only get in the way of actual work.

Answer (score 4):

Citing the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) (emphasis is mine):

> `Nothing` is removed *as part of the standard evaluation process*. It
>   is **not removed** in expressions that are held or inactive.

So it should be removed upon evaluation, what actually happens, and there is no statement that it should be removed from the original unevaluated list.

Comment: I would agree if I used `SetDelayed`. However, I used `Set`.

Comment: @Edmund You used `Part` which is very special in *Mathematica* because it allows *in-place* modification of a list without evaluation of the whole list!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is exactly a bug. But it is at minimum a woefully underdocumented feature, and identical to one that shows up when using Sequence[]. If you use `Information` you will get an idea of what is happening.

```
datN[[First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN

(* Out[891]= {2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)

Information[datN]
(* Global`datN
datN={2,1,3,Nothing,1,2,5,2,2,2} *)
```

Now repeat:

```
datN[[First@FirstPosition[5]@datN]] = Nothing;
datN

(* Out[912]= {2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2} *)
In[913]:= Information[datN]

(* Global`datN
datN={2,1,3,Nothing,1,Nothing,5,2,2,2} *)
```

The problem is as follows. `First@FirstPosition[5]@datN` evaluates `datN`, hence gets it's positioning "correct", that is, for the list with the `Nothing` removed. `Part`, when used as a left-hand-side of an expression (what we call "setpart"), is not actually evaluating `datN`. This is a mismatch.

I am not sure if there is a sound reason for this behavior of setpart. It might be necessitated by the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Set`. This behavior goes back to version 1 I believe, so I'd be quite reluctant to mess with it even if Set semantics might allow for that.

Comment: Clearly I have to live with it as it is. However, at this moment, I don't feel it is intuitively correct. At least I understand its mechanism.

Comment: "I am not sure if there is a sound reason for this behavior of setpart." ← I think there is.  I would find it quite disturbing if it didn't behave this way.  To make it behave the way @Edmund thought it did would require evaluating the list in its entirety when only one element is being set. Now consider `arr = {1,x,2};  x = 42;` If `arr[[3]] = Sequence[]` triggered an evaluation of all of `arr` and re-setting it to the evaluation result, it would change it to `arr = {1,42}` instead of `arr = {1,x}`.  That would be rather confusing.  Also, what if evaluating `x` has side effects, e.g. ...

Comment: ... `x := Print["foo"];`?  Even more confusing if `x` gets evaluated just because a *different* element of `arr` was changed!  Of course in principle `arr[[3]] = Sequence[]` (or `Nothing`) could be made to remove the 3rd element without re-evaluating any other part of the list.  But that would mean adding extra special properties to `Sequence[]/Nothing` that are unrelated to what they do at the moment.  That would add additional complexity to and already complex language with too many surprising behaviours.  At least the current behaviour is quite simple and clear once one understands it.

Comment: All good points, @Szabolcs. Though the current behavior has its anomalies. For example one could eval the list in intermediate steps in the current scheme, e.g. using side effects, and get inconsistencies. But overall I agree with you, the present semantics are the better way to go.