# Evaluation of an iterator construct containing Sequence in Table

Tags: functions, evaluation, iterators

The following code:

```
Table[i*j, Apply[Sequence , {{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}}]]
```

returns the error:

> Table::nliter: Non-list iterator Sequence@@{{i,1,3},{j,1,2}} at
> position 2 does not evaluate to a real numeric value.

On the other hand, the following alternative (which should be completely equivalent) works fine:

```
Table[i*j, Sequence[{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}]]
```

My questions:

- Why is the first version not working while the last one is?
- How can I make the first line work in the simplest manner possible?

This is a subroutine I would need for a more complicated function.

Comment: `MemberQ[Attributes[Table], HoldAll]` gives `True`, so you need to do `Table[i*j, Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, {{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}}]]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sequence` is special. As mentioned in **Details** section of document of `Sequence`:

> `Sequence` objects will automatically be flattened out in all functions except those with attribute `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete`.

Indeed, `HoldAll` doesn't stop `Sequence`:

```
Hold[a, Sequence[b, c], d]
(* Hold[a, b, c, d] *)
```

The standard way to fix the first sample is, as mentioned by J.M. in the comment above, using `Evaluate`. Alternatively, you can:

```
With[{iter = Apply[Sequence, {{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}}]}, Table[i*j, iter]]

Table[i*j, ##] &@Apply[Sequence, {{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}}]
```

Related discussion can be found in **Possible Issues** section of document of `Table` BTW.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that, though `Table` owns `HoldAll` attribute, it doesn't mean it never evaluate its arguments. You may want to read the following post:

[Unexpected behaviour from Table[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124046/1871)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
ReleaseHold[HoldForm[Table][i*j, Apply[Sequence, {{i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}}]]]
(*{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}*)
```