# How to generate a tensor by a given list, which specifies the ranges and dimensions of the tensor?

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, tensors, table

I am trying to create a function that generates a tensor according to a list, each of whose elements specifies the range of the corresponding dimension of the tensor and whose length specifies the total dimension of the tensor. I tried two versions using mainly "Table" and "Splice" functions.

**Version 1:**

```
ClearAll[i]
imax = {2, 3, 4};
Table[i[n], {n, Length[imax]}]
Table[{i[n], imax[[n]]}, {n, Length[imax]}]
Table[%%, Splice[%, Table]]
```

which produces

```
{i[1], i[2], i[3]}
{{i[1], 2}, {i[2], 3}, {i[3], 4}}
Table[%%, Splice[%, Table]]
```

where "Splice" fails to work.

**Version 2:**

```
ClearAll[i]
imax = {2, 3, 4};
Table[i[n], {n, Length[imax]}]
Table[{i[n], imax[[n]]}, {n, Length[imax]}]
Table[%%, Splice[{{i[1], 2}, {i[2], 3}, {i[3], 4}}, Table]]
```

which produces

```
{i[1], i[2], i[3]}
{{i[1], 2}, {i[2], 3}, {i[3], 4}}
{{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 
    2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}, {{1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 
    3, 4}}}, {{{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 4}}, {{2, 2, 
    1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}, {{2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 
    3, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}}}
```

where "Splice" works as expected.

**Questions:**

1. Why "Splice" does not work in the first version?
2. How can I embed "Splice" properly into "Table", so that I could make a function such as

```
TensorByList[list_]:=Module[{tensor},...;tensor]
```

which creates a tensor without a need to setup the iterators, which was the case with "Table" when I want to create a high dimension tensor:

```
Table[{i1,i2,...},{i1,i1max},{i2,i2max},...]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I will admit that I cannot understand your question; but try: `Array[List, {2, 3, 4}]`. A good question should **(1)** present the task that needs to be accomplished,  **(2)** input data available in copy-paste-able form, and **(3)** desired output. Optionally, you can provide other details. As presented, your question is asking the participants primarily to do a code review.

Comment: According to document of `Splice`: "`Splice` is resolved as part of the standard evaluation process. It is not resolved in expressions that are held or inactive. " `Table` is a function with `HoldAll` attribute (it does analyze its argument to some degree, though), so the behavior of **version 1** is actually expected, and the standard way to fix the code is to use `Evaluate`: `Table[%%, Evaluate@Splice[%, Table]]`. So, the real problem is not "Why "Splice" does not work in the first version?", but "Why "Splice" works in the second version?", which I'm not sure how to answer.

Comment: @Syed Indeed, the code sample given by OP isn't minimal, but (s)he isn't asking for code review. This is definitely an on-topic problem about the core language. (Particularly related to evaluation order and the surprisng evaluation mechanism of `Table` and `Splice`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270864/1871

Comment: @xzczd, I stand corrected then. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Syed  As currently written, I won't say it's a good question, though :) . The question could of course be more focused.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your replies! Yes, I was not familiar with Array and that solution using Array definitely works! This is my first attempt to post a question here and I may improve the quality of questions in the future!

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your replies! I was also curious about the usage of Splice and the mechanism of the evaluation order. I will try the Evaluate function and study the mechanism further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to use "Array" instead of "Table" and "Splice" because "Array" takes a list of dimensions:

```
i = 1;
tensor = Array[a[i++] &, imax];
tensor // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Interesting use of increment here! Can you give any hint as to your intuition when writing this?

Comment: a[i++] simply numerates the different tensor elements.