# Why the difference in performance? Array vs List and `Delete` vs `Nothing`

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, assignment

In a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118108/using-sequence-to-delete-a-part-of-an-expression) I was warned against the use of `Nothing` to delete elements from a list, and rather use `Delete`. Being of an inquisitive nature, I investigated the performance hit when using `Nothing` instead of `Delete`

```
n = 300;
data2 = Table[0.0, n, 500, 18]  (* Create some data. This is more-or-less the shape and quantity of my real-life data. *)

timing = {{"Nothing[]", "Delete[]"}}; (* Create a list to contain the timing data *)
For[j = 0, j < 50, j++,  (* Run 50 trials of timing measurements *)
 data3 = data2; (* Create a copy of the data *)
 i = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {10, 1}]; (* Select the elements that should be deleted *)
 ii = Flatten[i];
 t1 = AbsoluteTiming[data3[[ii]] = Nothing; data3 = data3;]; (* Delete the data using Nothing, and time it. *)
 data3 = data2; (* Use the original data again *)
 t2 = AbsoluteTiming[data3 = Delete[data3, i];]; (* Delete the data using Delete[], and time it. *)
 AppendTo[timing, {First[t1], First[t2]}] (* Record the times *)
 ]
ListPlot[{timing[[2 ;;, 1]], timing[[2 ;;, 2]]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> timing[[1]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Trial no.", "AbsoluteTiming"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Single delete"]
```

(In the plots below the blue markers represent the `Nothing` method and the yellow markers `Delete`.)

[image: ListPlot comparing the computational times of Delete and Nothing to delete an element from an array]

As can be expected, the `Nothing` method is much slower than `Delete`, and the story should end here. But this did not agree with my experience using other data. After spending too much of my employer's time on finding out what the differences are exactly, I found that replacing a single element of the data with something arbitrary (`data2 [[3]] = x`) turns `data2` from an array into a list of lists, and this makes `Nothing` perform better than `Delete`.

[image: ListPlot comparing the computational times of Delete and Nothing to delete an element from a list of lists]

But the real surprise is that both seem to be orders of magnitude faster when operating on the 'list of lists' than on the matrix. I imagine that Mathematica's array functions are highly efficient, so I feel that I am missing something. Does my test do what I think it does? Is there a better way to use `Delete`, or are there better functions for deletion that I don't know of? Is there a better way to run the tests?

---

Following a suggestion in the comments, I did some more timings:

```
data2 = Table[0.0, n, 500, 18];
data3 = data2 
data3[[3]] = "Data" // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.*10^-7, "Data"} *)

data3 = data2 
data3[[3, 3, 3]] = 1. // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {1.*10^-7, 1.} *)
```

But

```
data3 = data2 
data3[[3]] = {data2[[2]]} ; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {0.0432838, Null} *)
data3 = data2 
data3[[3]] = data2[[2]] ; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* {0.0134969, Null} *)
```

This is how I would expect it: copying parts of arrays is much more efficient than copying lists.

More relevant perhaps are the memory requirements:

```
|          | ByteCount | LeafCount |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|data2     |21 600 160 | 2 850 301 | 
|data3     |72 989 696 | 2 840 801 |
```

So for the deletion problem above, the trade-off is speed for memory.

Answer (score 7):

`data2[[3]] = x; // AbsoluteTiming` might give a hint.

I explain it to myself as follows: At that point when you execute `data2[[3]] = x`, all rows other than row 3 are internally copied to packed arrays and `data2` is replaced by a list of pointers to those. Now all following operations are performed with an array of pointers. Of course, this is significantly faster as the packed arrays with the actual data do not have to be touched at all ...

However, this comes at a price: The output is no more a packed array, so subsequent operations on it may be slowed down.

Comment: data3[[3]] = "Data" // AbsoluteTiming yields {1.*10^-7, "Data"}

Comment: Ah, you have to measure the timing right after `data2` has been generated with `data2 = Table[0.0, n, 500, 18] `. At this point, `data2` is still a packed array; and `data2[[3]] = "Data";` will enforce the unpacking (the copyingand replacement by pointers that I described above). When `data2` is already unpacked, then `data2[[3]] = "Data";` is indeed super fast. Because of the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: data3 = data2 
data3[[3]] = "Data" // AbsoluteTiming yields {1.*10^-7, "Data"}
data3 = data2
data3[[3, 3, 3]] = 1. // AbsoluteTiming yields {1.*10^-7, 1.}

But 

data3 = data2
data3[[3]] = {data2[[2]]} ; // AbsoluteTiming yields {0.0432838, Null}
data3 = data2
data3[[3]] = data2[[2]] ; // AbsoluteTiming yields {0.0134969, Null}

This is how I would expect it.

More relevant perhaps are the memory requirements:

         ByteCount LeafCount
data2 21600160 2850301
data3 72989696 2840801

For my (interactive) application I will happily trade memory for speed..

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment: I didn't realize there wasn't any layout possible in the comments.

Comment: Don't mind. Btw., layout _is_ possible. You just have to use backticks for code markup... =)

Comment: You can convert `data2` into a list of packed arrays with `data3 = List@@data2`. Then you should have the best of both worlds: Deletion at the highest level is fast and the lower levels are still packed which should keep the memory consumption at bay.