# Map at a subsequence of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I'm trying to construct a function somewhat similar to `MapAt`. A basic usage example should look like this:

```
list = {a, b, c, d};
MapAtSequence[f, list, 2;;3]
(* {a, f[b, c], d} *)
```

Or with specific numbers and functions

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
MapAtSequence[Plus, list, 2;;3]
(* {1, 5, 4} *)
```

I'm not attached to the idea of using `Span`, a list of positions may also be ok, but so far I only have the need to apply a function to neighboring elements.

Here's my minimal working example:

```
MapAtSequence[f_, list_, span_] := Module[{l = list, output},
    l[[span]] = f[Sequence @@ l[[span]]];
    output = Drop[l, {(First@span) + 1, Last@span}]
]
```

This appears to work as intended, but is clearly good only for 1D lists. A pitfall awaits me if the applied function generates a list of the same length as the span (see somewhat related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/setting-parts-of-a-list)). A similar pitfall awaits if my function generates a `Sequence`.

Moreover, I have a feeling this isn't an efficient or elegant way to get the job done. After all, at first glance the task sounds really simple - I need to splice a function into the list, for example go from this:

```
{a,      b, c , d} (* to this: *)
{a, Plus[b, c], d} (* <---|    *)
```

How can I improve my code and generalize it to multidimensional lists?

**Edit:**

For a certain set of functions such as `Plus` and `Times` my problem can be formulated in a simpler manner:

How can I replace some neighboring commas in a list to the infix notation of a function, e.g.:

```
{a, b,     c,     d, e}
{a, b~Plus~c~Plus~d, e}
```

Comment: I am certain that this question has been asked before, if not here on Stack Overflow, though perhaps not in this detail.  Can anyone find it?

Comment: Could well be, although I didn't manage to find this on SE initially. Googling is an art in its own right :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pattern matching approach:

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

MapAtSequence1[f_, list_, span_] := 
  list /. {Sequence @@ list[[;; Last@span]], e___} :> 
          {Sequence @@ list[[;; First@span - 1]], f @@ list[[span]], e}

MapAtSequence1[g, list, 2 ;; 4]
```

> `{a, g[b, c, d]}`

An approach using `Join`

```
MapAtSequence2[f_, list_, span_] := 
  list[[;; First@span - 1]]~Join~{f @@ list[[span]]}~Join~list[[Last@span + 1 ;;]]

MapAtSequence2[f, list, 3 ;; 4]
```

> `{a, b, f[c, d]}`

(For this function the end of the `Span` must be given as an integer. Something like `2;;` will not work as `Last@span` would be `All`.)

For multidimensional lists

```
MapAtSequence2[f_, list_, span_, sublist_] := 
  MapAt[MapAtSequence2[f, #, span] &, list, {sublist}]

list = {{a, b, c, b, c, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}}
MapAtSequence2[f, list, 2 ;; 4, {1}]
```

> `{{a, f[b, c, b], c, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}}`

and

```
MapAtSequence2[f, #, 3 ;; 4] & /@ list
```

> `{{a, b, f[c, b], c, b, c, d}, {a, b, f[c, d], e, f, g}}`

One approach using `Insert` and `Drop` (improved according to the comment by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard))

```
MapAtSequence3[f_, list_, span_] := 
  Insert[Drop[list, span], Unevaluated[f @@ list[[span]]], First@span]
MapAtSequence3[f_, list_, span_, sublist_] := 
  MapAt[MapAtSequence3[f, #, span] &, list, sublist]
```

Or

```
MapAtSequence4[f_, list_, span_] := Module[{tL = list},
  tL[[First@span]] = f @@ tL[[span]]; 
  tL[[First@span + 1 ;; Last@span]] = Sequence[];
  tL]
MapAtSequence4[f_, list_, span_, sublist_] := 
  Module[{tL = list},
  tL[[sublist, First@span]] = f @@ tL[[sublist, span]]; 
  tL[[sublist, First@span + 1 ;; Last@span]] = Sequence[];
  tL]
```

---

**Benchmarking**

1) List Length (Sequence Length 2)

```
list[n_] := list[n] = RandomInteger[10, n]
Do[list[n], {n, 1, 1000}]

benchListLength[mas_, maxLength_, span_] := Table[
  {n, First@AbsoluteTiming@Do[mas[f, list[n], span], {1000}]},
  {n, 3, maxLength}]

ListPlot[benchListLength[#, 1000, 2 ;; 3] & /@ {MapAtSequence1, 
  MapAtSequence2, MapAtSequence3, MapAtSequence4}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"List Length", "AbsoluteTiming of 1000 Runs"}, 
  LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 12, ImageSize -> 450, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[7], 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{MapAtSequence1, MapAtSequence2, MapAtSequence3, 
  MapAtSequence4}, LegendMarkerSize -> 7], {After, Top}]
```

[image: ListLengthBenching]

2) Sequence Length (List Length 1000)

```
benchSeqLength[mas_] := Table[
  {n, First@AbsoluteTiming@Do[mas[f, list[1000], 2 ;; n], {1000}]},
  {n, 3, 1000}]

ListPlot[benchSeqLength[#] & /@ {MapAtSequence1, MapAtSequence2, 
  MapAtSequence3, MapAtSequence4}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Sequence Length", "AbsoluteTiming of 1000 Runs"}, 
  LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 12, ImageSize -> 450, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[7], 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{MapAtSequence1, MapAtSequence2, MapAtSequence3, 
  MapAtSequence4}, LegendMarkerSize -> 7], {After, Top}]
```

[image: SequenceLengthBenching]

3) Very long lists
[image: VeryLongListsBenching]

Comment: I'm afraid, this is even worse than my approach. Consider `list = {a, b, c, b, c, d};
list /. {s___, Sequence @@ list[[4 ;; 5]], e___} :> {s, 
   f @@ list[[4 ;; 5]], e}` which finds the required sequence at positions `2;;3` and replaces those.

Comment: However the approach using `Join` gets my upvote. The question of generalizing to multidimensional lists still remains, but one solution looks like using `MapAt` to select the necessary sublist with the function passed to `MapAt` being your version of `MapAtSequence`.

Comment: Note to other readers: Karstens's latest edit renders my first comment irrelevant.

Comment: I will only need to apply `MapAtSequence` within one list, so you could write something like `MapAtNested[f_,list_, index_, span_] := MapAt[MapAtSequence[f,#,span]&,list,index]`. Would you like to expand this to an answer or shall I?

Comment: Fair enough, will do

Comment: Kudos for the benchmarking! It's interesting, how flat `MapAtSequence2` is vs. sequence length. Could be, that for a sufficiently long sequence it might beat `MapAtSequence3` Would you be so kind as to share the details of the tests?

Comment: You might consider: `MapAtSequence3[f_, list_, span_] := 
 Insert[Drop[list, span], Unevaluated[ f @@ list[[span]] ], First@span]` -- this should handle additional forms that the current version does not.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP for very long lists and sequences `MapAtSequence2` does beat `MapAtSequence3`. Also notice the edited more general definition for `MapAtSequence3` following the recommendation by [Mr.Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard). The benchmarks shown are updated using the new definition and extended for longer lists and sequences.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks for the input, I really wish I could upvote this more.